# MS Graph API GetActivitiesByInterval gives blank itemActivitySet

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Busy writing some implementation on the beta branch of MS Graph API.

Using [GetActivitiesByInterval](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/itemactivity-getbyinterval?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http), it brings back the activity stats (how many activities / how many actors) but no activity sets ([itemActivitySet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/itemactionset?view=graph-rest-beta))

```
{
    "StartDateTime": "2023-01-12T00:00:00+00:00",
    "EndDateTime": "2023-01-12T23:59:59+00:00",
    "Access": {
        "ActionCount": 4,
        "ActorCount": 1,
        "AdditionalData": {
            "timeSpentInSeconds": 0
        },
        "ODataType": "microsoft.graph.itemActionStat"
    },
    "Create": null,
    "Delete": null,
    "Edit": null,
    "Move": null,
    "IsTrending": null,
    "IncompleteData": {
        "MissingDataBeforeDateTime": null,
        "WasThrottled": false,
        "AdditionalData": {
            "resultsPending": false,
            "notSupported": false
        },
        "ODataType": "microsoft.graph.incompleteData"
    },
    "Activities": null,
    "Id": null,
    "ODataType": "#microsoft.graph.itemActivityStat",
    "AdditionalData": {
        "aggregationInterval": "None"
    }
}
```

There were definitely activities on those, a comment, a rename and a move. I can check those activities are on SharePoint.

I've also tried adding query option expand=activities on returning the drive item but that gives back an empty set (not null, just no data filled with "[],")

There also doesn't seem to be a hidden list called "userActivityFeedHiddenList" in SharePoint that I could use to reference activities for a particular file.

I've googled quite a bit to try and get as much information and went through quite a number of SO posts (hence all the things I tried) but none has worked.

Any suggestions?

Comment: the response type of this api is [itemActivityStats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/itemactivity-getbyinterval?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#response) but not the `itemActivitySet`. could you pls let us know where you see the api would return `itemActivitySet`?

Comment: @TinyWang If you look at the response I receive, and check the linked itemActivitySet, you will note that "Create","Delete","Edit","Move" in the abovementioned response are itemActivitySets. You can see what itemActivityStat resource type responds with here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/itemactivitystat?view=graph-rest-beta, which is linked in the first sentence on the page I linked in the documentation "Get itemActivityStats for the activities that took place under this resource within the specified time interval"

Comment: It's possible that the activity sets (itemActivitySet) are not returned because the feature is not fully supported in the beta branch of the MS Graph API.